# removing all faces programmatically in OBJ file

Tags: regex, string, 3d

I have a program which spits out OBJ files from a kinect 3d recording. each obj file is a series of vertices and faces. Vertices appear like this:

v 0.211181 0.436763 1.052000

and faces appear like this:

f 15734/15734 15560/15560 15559/15559

Each obj file has about 100,000 lines of vertices and faces, so I need to be able to delete the faces programmatically. Anyone have a solution for this. I basically just need to write code that says: "for each line, if it starts with an f, remove all characters in this line."

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: How are you processing the obj file for the modification?

Comment: You don't have to use regex to do this. You can just check if first char is equal to f. If yes delete the line. If you really want to use regex you can replace `'/^f .+/'` with `''`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to load the obj file in Notepad++.

Then use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> (replace)

Select "Regular Expression" radio button in the Search Mode box in the bottom left
(making sure the matches newline tickbox is unticked)

Find What: `^f.*\n`

Replace With:

This will remove every line which starts with "f". If you want to keep the blank lines rather than remove them entirely, remove the `\n` from the end of the Find string.

Comment: Or you could simply use sed from command line works like charm for many files. So try: sed -i".bak" "/^f/d" *.obj